# Добавляю один код на сайт, перестаёт работать другой

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите решить проблему. Я в программировании вообще полный ноль, но постараюсь описать. На сайте *discontica.ru* есть счётчик отсчёта времени до завершения акции, когда добавляю форму подписки от smartresponder, счётчик перестаёт отображаться. ошибка из консоли Хрома

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'countdown' 
(anonymous function)
p.fireWith 
e.extend.ready 
c.addEventListener.B
```

**Код смартреспондера**

```
_sr(function() {
    _sr('form[name="SR_form_133596_7"]').find('div#sr-preload_').prop('id', 'sr-preload_133596_7');
    _sr('#sr-preload_133596_7').css({'width':parseInt(_sr('form[name="SR_form_133596_7"]').width() + 'px'), 'height':parseInt(_sr('form[name="SR_form_133596_7"]').height()) + 'px', 'line-height':parseInt(_sr('form[name="SR_form_133596_7"]').height()) + 'px'}).show();
    if(_sr('form[name="SR_form_133596_7"]').find('input[name="script_url_133596_7"]').length) {
        _sr.ajax({
            url: _sr('input[name="script_url_133596_7"]').val() + '/' + (typeof document.charset !== 'undefined' ? document.charset : document.characterSet),
            dataType: "script",
            success: function() {
                _sr('#sr-preload_133596_7').hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Код счётчика**

```
(function($) {
$.fn.countdown = function (date, options) {
    options = $.extend({
        lang: {
            years:   ['год', 'года', 'лет'],
            months:  ['месяц', 'месяца', 'месяцев'],
            days:    ['день', 'дня', 'дней'],
            hours:   ['час', 'часа', 'часов'],
            minutes: ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут'],
            seconds: ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд'],
            plurar:  function(n) {
                return (n % 10 == 1 && n % 100 != 11 ? 0 : n % 10 >= 2 && n % 10 <= 4 && (n % 100 < 10 || n % 100 >= 20) ? 1 : 2);
            }
        },
        prefix: "Осталось: ",
        finish: "Всё"
    }, options);

    var timeDifference = function(begin, end) {
        if (end < begin) {
            return false;
        }
        var diff = {
            seconds: [end.getSeconds() - begin.getSeconds(), 60],
            minutes: [end.getMinutes() - begin.getMinutes(), 60],
            hours: [end.getHours() - begin.getHours(), 24],
            days: [end.getDate()  - begin.getDate(), new Date(begin.getYear(), begin.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate()],
            months: [end.getMonth() - begin.getMonth(), 12],
            years: [end.getYear()  - begin.getYear(), 0]
        };
        var result = new Array();
        var flag = false;
        for (i in diff) {
            if (flag) {
                diff[i][0]--;
                flag = false;
            }
            if (diff[i][0] < 0) {
                flag = true;
                diff[i][0] += diff[i][1];
            }
            if (!diff[i][0]) continue;
            result.push(diff[i][0] + ' ' + options.lang[i][options.lang.plurar(diff[i][0])]);
        }
        return result.reverse().join(' ');
    };
    var elem = $(this);
    var timeUpdate = function () {
        var s = timeDifference(new Date(), date);
        if (s.length) {
            elem.html(options.prefix + s);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
            elem.html(options.finish);
        }
    };
    timeUpdate();
    var timer = setInterval(timeUpdate, 1000);
};
```

})(jQuery);

Надеюсь, что выложил именно те куски, которые нужны. Заранее благодарен откликнувшимся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть у вас такая же проблема как тут: [Конфликт формы `Smartresponder` с плагинами в `WordPress`](http://www.onwordpress.ru/conflict-smartresponder-adn-wordpress.html)

Comment: Спасибо, именно в этом и была проблема. Теперь всё работает